# How to make Liferay not produce condensed HTML code?

Tags: java, html, jsp, liferay

I found that Liferay transfers my JSP code in a somehow "condensed" way -- putting most of the text into a few very long lines.

This makes it uncomfortable to debug javascript.

Is it possible to turn off this feature temporary?

Comment: I suggest a better (real) JS debug tool, such as Firebug or Chrome dev tools.

Comment: One I am using is Firebug. Does it have an option to autoformat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML Minification is on regardless you're in developer mode or not since HTML stripping can itself produce problems you want to see in developer mode.

You can add `strip=0` parameter to the URL to prevent the served HTML page being stripped.

In order to turn HTML-Stripping completely off change in your `system.properties`:

```
com.liferay.filters.strip.StripFilter=false
```

But as @BalusC said you should use a tool which does the formatting when debugging. So you're not bothered by the stripping.

Answer (score 12):

For others looking at this post, if you simply want to do this on an adhoc basis you can add these params to the URL:

> /web/guest/page?**js_fast_load=0&css_fast_load=0&strip=0**

Note this is for JS, CSS and HTML

Comment: Wow, nothing can be quickier and flexible than this!

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do it. Copy the following in portal-ext.properties and restart the server

```
javascript.fast.load=false
```

or If you dont want to restart and its just for temporary purpose add `js_fast_load` parameter to url and set its value to false.

For example if you are in a page `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home` in which your portlet or the javascript is present. Use this url instead `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?js_fast_load=0`

Comment: This is only for JS-Files, isn't it? I am not sure, but I think OP worries about debugging Javascript that is inside HTML-Code and not in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay has a file named portal-developer.properties as template in WEB-INF/classes. You can either reference this or just copy/paste the content into your portal-ext.properties.

This has several options to minify html, js, css and others. You'll kill your loading time - i.e. you really only want these options at development time, but then it really helps.

By default all files are also combined into a single one (for js, another for css etc.) - with the development options you'll get a separate request for every file on every page request.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to update package name for Liferay 6.2 from @Fabian Barney's answer:

```
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter=false
```